# Lua loadfile() cannot find file in same directory

Tags: c++, lua

Odd problem here.
I have a Lua script ('human.lua') that is executed through `dofile()` in a C++ application.

I attempt to load another file which is an AI script in a pretty standard way on the first line:

```
behavior_chunk = assert(loadfile("testBehavior.lua"))
```

This throws 'cannot open testBehavior.lua: no such file or directory".
testBehavior.lua is in the same dir as human.lua.

How is this happening?
Could package.path be getting set erroneously somehow?
I have done a lot of research on this and cannot find what may be causing this specific problem.

Maybe I'm missing something really obvious.

Comment: How did you load `human.lua`?

Comment: `package.path` does not affect `loadfile` and friends.

Comment: I use dofile to run the 'human.lua' script.


`std::string fullname = "scripts/"+(std::string)name;  
  
    if(luaL_dofile(pLua,fullname.c_str())){  fprintf(stderr,"Could not run Lua script file: %s\n",lua_tostring(pLua,-1));  
}`

Answer (score 2):

The `loadfile` path is relative to working directory, not relative to script location. So if you started Lua from folder `A` to run `B\human.lua`, then `loadfile("C/testBehavior.lua")` from `human.lua` looks for `testBehavior.lua` in `A/C`, not in `B/C`.

So if your folder structure is:

```
Foo
  yourLuaApp.exe
  Scripts   
    human.lua   
    file1.lua   
    file2.lua   
    ai   
      testBehavior.lua
```

and say you have C++

```
int main(argc, char* argv[])
{
    ... init Lua ...
    std::string fullname = "scripts/" + argv[1];
    if (luaL_dofile(pLua, fullname.c_str()))
        std::cerr << "error" << endl;
    else
        std::cout << "success" << endl;
}
```

then you will get these results:

```
C:\Foo> yourLuaApp.exe file1.lua
success
C:\Foo> yourLuaApp.exe ai\testBehavior.lua
success
```

but

```
C:\Foo\Scripts> ../yourLuaApp.exe file1.lua 
error
```

because you are starting your app from `Scripts` folder, which does not contain a folder called `Scripts`.

Comment: It's relative to the current working directory. If you double click on a .lua file in Windows, then the working directory is probably the directory where Lua is in.

Comment: Thanks guys.
Here is how I run the script in C++:

    std::string fullname = "scripts/"+(std::string)name;

    if(luaL_dofile(pLua,fullname.c_str())){
        fprintf(stderr,"Could not run Lua script file:  %s\n",lua_tostring(pLua,-1));
    }

Comment: So what should be done to load other lua scripts with a relative location?

Either in the same folder, or in a sub-folder?

My scripts folder structure is like this:

`>Scripts  
human.lua  
file1.lua  
file2.lua  
>>ai  
humanBehavior.lua`

Comment: I'm not sure? Please elaborate.

Comment: @user3418022 Updated, I hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the update.

However loading the script in C++ works flawlessly, the problem comes in when I load a Lua script from WITHIN that Lua script I loaded from C++:

```
behavior_chunk = assert(loadfile("testBehavior.lua"))
```

How would I correctly use loadfile from inside a Lua script (not C++) to load another Lua file in the same directory, or in a sub-directory?

My reasoning is that I loaded 'human.lua' from the 'scripts' dir in C++. Now inside 'human.lua' I load another script that is located in the same directory as that script, so why wouldn't that work?

Maybe I didn't make this clear enough. I apologize if that's the case.